# Java Access Modifiers keyword (private, default, protected, public or final, static etc..) automatically hide in eclipse but show in source file

Tags: java, eclipse, automation, coding-style

When I write code that time automatically hide some java keyword in eclipse but display in .java file from directory.

Eclipse editor screen shot:

[image: In Eclipse showing like that]

.java file screen shot:

[image: .java file code]

Please help me !!

Comment: A screenshot of eclipse is better to show us the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! There should be a minimum content in one question: Input sample (if needed), expected output sample (is needed), what you try, what you research... Please, show us your error. (Screenshots)

Comment: I'd like a screenshot as well because such a behavior looks _really_ odd to me, especially if you face it on different versions of Eclipse IDE. Did you install any plug-in? Is your class located in an opened Java project? Are you sure JDT (Java Development Tools) is installed (should be the case by default in most Eclipse IDE packages)?

Comment: I have not install any plug-in.Yes my class located in opened Java project !!

Comment: try Eclipse --> Preferences --> Editor --> Reset to Default

Comment: Eclipse doesn't do this. Show us the actual contents of the file in your screenshot rather than an  example of what it 'should be'.

Comment: @greg-449 Please see .java file screen short . I just added

Comment: Unfortunately, the screenshot is cropped and does not show with which editor the file is opened. If you select everything (Ctrl+A) and do a copy and paste into a `.txt` file, are the Java keywords missing or will they appear again? If you right-click the file and choose _Open With_, which editor is selected?

Comment: @howlger When I copy code from eclipse and paste in .txt file then they appear, and right-click the file and choose Open With 'Text Editor' then also they appear !!

Comment: Maybe characters in bold are not displayed. Does in _Window > Preferences: Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring_ deactivating bold for _Java > Keywords excluding 'return'_ make them visible in the Java editor? If yes, in _Window > Preferences: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts_ choose a different font for _Java > Java Editor Text Font_. Make also sure not using an outdated Java and Eclipse IDE version.

Comment: @howlger It's work !! Many Many Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the complete code can be copied proves that the characters exist but are not displayed.

If in *Window > Preferences: Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring* deactivating bold for *Java > Keywords excluding 'return'* make them visible in the Java editor again, only characters in bold are affected. In this case choosing a different font at least for the Java editor might be the solution:

1. In ***Window > Preferences: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts*** choose a **different font** for **Java > Java Editor Text Font**

I like [Source Code Pro](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro) as a font for coding, which has to be installed in the operating system to use it in Eclipse.

Make also sure not using an outdated Java and Eclipse IDE version.